# Avoiding fallback on react code-splitting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, code-splitting

I've been working on a react project and I implemented route-based code-splitting on it. It is fine and working but now I want it to not display the loader when the next page is not fully loaded. How can I retain the old page UI and make use horizontal loader on the top of the viewport so that when it is still downloading the next page it will display the horizontal loader and when finished display the next page. Is that even possible in route-based? Because there is a solution in react using startTransition but it is used with state. Hope anyone can help me with these.

I am using react-router-dom v5.2.0, react v16.13.1